# Reduce vs Filter and Map

Tags: javascript

I've written a function that computes the square of only the positive integers  in the array realNumberArray and returns a new array with the result.

example:
[4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]
returns [16,1764,36]

How would you recreate the following function using only reduce() and what would be the preferred way?

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  const squaredIntegers = arr;
  let newArr=squaredIntegers.filter(val=>val%1==0 && val>0).map(val=>Math.pow(val,2))
  return newArr;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Comment: I would advise to keep your version with `map` and `filter` - it's much more obvious what is going on than when you use `reduce`. (This is a general rule, in fact - you can do more or less anything with `reduce`, whereas `map` and `filter` make it clear what you're doing.) I guess `reduce` in theory has better performance (since you only pass through the array once), but I wouldn't worry about this unless you're dealing with huge arrays and you actually notice performance being a problem.

Comment: I agree, I prefer readability over microscopic performance gains, but don't forget to align your code if it later impacts the overall speed. However, beware that using a spread operator in the oneliner reducers or even just using concat will also have an expensive overhead that you may avoid. I you want to enumerate only once and you don't want to heat up the GC, stick with push inside the reduce.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const squareList = arr =>
  arr.reduce((out, x) => x % 1 === 0 && x > 0 ? [...out, x * x] : out, []);

console.log(squareList([4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Push to the accumulator only if the test passes:

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = arr => arr.reduce((a, val) => {
  if (val % 1 == 0 && val > 0) {
    a.push(val ** 2);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this via the following:

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const result = realNumberArray.reduce((a, i) => Number.isInteger(i) && i > 0 ? a.concat([ i ** 2 ]) : a, [])

console.log(result)
```

To break this down, the code above reduces the input array `realNumberArray` to the `result` array where for each reduce iteration:

1. the input value being iterated is "filtered" if it is a whole numbers via `Number.isInteger(number)`. If the number `i` is an integer then the code
2. proceeds to concatenate the "square" of that number to the output array `a` via this `a.concat([ i ** 2 ])` (note that `number ** 2` is shorthand for `Math(number, 2)`
3. if `i` is not an integer, then it's filtered out by directly returning the current output array `a` for that iteration

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  const squaredIntegers = arr;
  let newArr = squaredIntegers.reduce((acc, val) => {
    if (val % 1 == 0 && val > 0) {
      acc.push(Math.pow(val, 2));
      return acc;
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
  return newArr;
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to check if `parseFloat()` and `parseInt()` on that number is same or not to figure out that the given number is pure integer. Then, based on your additional condition where the number should be greater than 0, add extra condition for that in the `if`.

```js
var arr = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2] ;
var res = arr.reduce((acc, num) => {
  if(num > 0 && parseFloat(num) === parseInt(num)){
    acc.push(num*num);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could concat an empty array of the sqared value, depending on the not integer value or if negative.

```js
const
    realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2],
    squareList = array => array.reduce((r, v) => r.concat(v % 1 || v < 0 ? [] : v * v), []),
    squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);

console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce((a,val)=>{
  if(val%1==0 && val>0)
  a.push(Math.pow(val,2))
  return a;
  },[])
};
const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce and Array destructuring instead of push method

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];

const newArray = realNumberArray.reduce((acc, curr) => (curr % 1 === 0 && curr >= 0 ? [...acc, curr * curr] : acc), []);
console.log(newArray);
```